# What permissions are required to create Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

Trying to create Azure Pipeline using Visual Studio 2019 and getting this error message:

> "The selected account doesn't have sufficient permissions to access
> this Azure DevOps project. You'll need to use a different account.

The account I'm using is the admin on Azure DevOps server, and also the Azure tenant admin. What specific permissions do I need to create an Azure pipeline, in addition to being admin?

[image: Azure Pipeline error]

Comment: As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#pipeline-permissions-reference) documentation, You need to have `Edit build Pipeline` permission in order to  create pipelines and save any changes to a build pipeline, including configuration variables, triggers, repositories, and retention policy.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT That is indeed what the documentation says but it doesn't seem to be true - at least for me.